# How can I dual boot my iphone or ipad to run a very simple custom os?

Tags: iphone, assembly, cpu-architecture

I am an experienced C/C++ programmer and have worked with assembly and many other programing language and I want to start a project as a learning process. I want to try and run a simple custom os on the iphone or ipad. What knowledge would I need to do this, and how does the iphone or ipad bootloader load the os and how could I modify it to load a custom os?

Im not really sure what to ask here so I really just need to get as much information as possible so I could ask some more informed questions to get my project started

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first objective is to find a way to launch custom code on the iphone/ipad. Unfortunately for you this is virtually impossible. Although some jailbreaks exist for the iphone, the flaws that allowed people to put their own custom code onto the phone have mostly been closed. It's possible to do it still but it creates a tethered jailbreak, which means upon resetting your device, you will lose any custom code you managed to get onto the phone/ipad.

I would suggest finding a different device to use for your experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to dual boot the iphone and have the second one boot into a custom os and the other into the standard iphone os? another question I have is does anyone have a link to what code I could use to send and receive data to and from an iphone via usb apple cord and c++ on windows.

Thanks

Comment: Like he said, you really can't do what you want. The iPhone is designed from the hardware up as a closed system. You would be better off with one of the Linux based handhelds.

Comment: the 2G and 3G iphones can be jailbroken untethered, it's only the 3GS and 4 (and some of the ipod touches?) that need a tethered jailbreak.

Comment: 3GS can be jailbroken without tethering now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [iphonelinux](http://linuxoniphone.blogspot.com/) project. It's in a very early stage and uses the same exploits that allow jailbreaking.